# OnCheckedChangeListener & OnClickListener in android -- Button half-works on first click, finishes on second click?

Tags: android, radio-button, onclicklistener, oncheckedchanged

Well... here's a problem it looks like I'm not the first to experience looking through other questions, however I can't find one that's Android-specific (others are C++ or straight java with different scenarios).

I have a calculator that determines your fuel mileage needs with given user inputs. The thing I'm adding now is a "burnoff" aspect where you can calculate the weight lost over the course of the race. Before adding the weight/burnoff element, everything worked fine.

Now, everything calculates normally ***except the weight*** on the first click.

On the second click (and subsequent clicks) it calculates properly. I suspect it has something to do with the switch statement and its location, but I could be wrong.... and even if I'm not, I'm not sure how to change it.

Looking for help on getting it all functioning properly on the first click. Thanks!

EDIT: The non-exception Toast text I put in as a debugger to determine if it was a math issue or what in the code. It pops up with "0.0" on the first click, then either "6.2" or "6.6" on subsequent clicks.

---

```
    package com.tomcat.performance;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class Fuelsimple extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

double fuelweight;

public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (checkedId){
    case R.id.rbMethanol:
        fuelweight = 6.6;
        break;
    case R.id.rbGasoline:
        fuelweight = 6.2;
        break;}
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fuelsimple);

RadioGroup rgFuelType = ((RadioGroup) findViewById (R.id.rgFuelType));
rgFuelType.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
RadioButton rbMethanol = ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMethanol));
RadioButton rbGasoline = ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbGasoline));

Button gen = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.submit));  
gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 



        public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

            EditText fuelUsed, pracLaps, featureLaps;

            pracLaps = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.pracLaps));
            fuelUsed = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.fuelUsed));
            featureLaps = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.featureLaps));
            TextView textLPGValue, textFuelNeededValue, textBurnoffValue;
            try{
            double pracLapsVar = Double.parseDouble(pracLaps.getText().toString());
            double fuelUsedVar = Double.parseDouble(fuelUsed.getText().toString());
            double featureLapsVar = Double.parseDouble(featureLaps.getText().toString());

            double efficiency = (pracLapsVar / fuelUsedVar);
            double fuelNeeded = (featureLapsVar / efficiency);
            double burnoff = (1.05 * (fuelNeeded * fuelweight));

            Toast andJelly = Toast.makeText(Fuelsimple.this, String.valueOf(fuelweight), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            andJelly.show();


            textLPGValue = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLPGValue));
            textFuelNeededValue = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFuelNeededValue));
            textBurnoffValue = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBurnoffValue));

            textLPGValue.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.3f", efficiency)) + " laps per gallon");
            textFuelNeededValue.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.3f", fuelNeeded)) + " gallons");
            textBurnoffValue.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", burnoff)) + " pounds");
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(Fuelsimple.this, "Please complete all fields and enter your fuel & lap info in decimals or whole numbers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); andEggs.show();} 
            catch (NullPointerException n) {Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(Fuelsimple.this, "Please enter ALL lap and fuel data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            andEggs.show();}
        }}
);      
}
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
    }
```

Comment: And what happens on the first click? Also as a recommendation, properly format the code you post.

Comment: First click calculates the laps per gallon (efficiency) and fuel needed with no problems whatsoever. The weight/burnoff remains at 0. On the second click, regardless of which button is selected to begin with, the burnoff then calculates.

Comment: Well, when you first start the application, if you don't select one of the checkboxes , `fuelweight` will be `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your variable fuelWeight is never initialized until a radio button is pressed.  The simplest way to fix this would be to call `setChecked(true)` on either rbmethanol or rbGasoline **after setting the listener**, maybe right below where you initialize those variables.  Doing it after setting the listener is important, because you want the switch statement to be resolved.  Right now, before you press a radio button, fuelWeight, as with all numeric primitive data types,  will be initialized to 0. This is probably the reason your first calculations are wrong.

Comment: Just tried that, Matt, and it's giving me the same results even with the button visibly checked.... once I click the radio button for the other option, then submit, it works perfectly on either.

Comment: Alright, maybe just set `fuelWeight` manually then, to whatever value you want to use as your default? So call `setChecked()` for whichever value you want, then, for example if Methanol is your default, `fuelWeight = 6.6`.  The first radio button is probably selected by default and won't trigger the listener if you re-select it, but I'm not testing this so I'm not sure.

Comment: Setting it to the default value seemed to work fine... afterwards, the listener picked up any changes and functioned properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at CheckChangeListener.It is called whenever the check state changes.

```
cbSave.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int visibility = isChecked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
                findViewById(R.id.nameInstructions).setVisibility(visibility);
                findViewById(R.id.name).setVisibility(visibility);

}
```